# Blazor Typeahead Issue

Tags: .net, blazor, typeahead

I've got a blazor typeahead issue. I have used Blazor typeahead as look up field which also acts as
searchable dropdown. Whenever I type something in typeahead field it searches accordingly but the main issue comes whenever I clear the text field with backspace(or by selecting all text and press backspace), it does not show all previous available list, that means the SearchMethod is not invoked after the last backspace.

Initially it was like:

[image: Initially it was like]

After searching something and clear the text filed with backspace it does not show all previous list:

[image: After searching something and clear the text filed with backspace it does not show all previous list]

My code looks like this,

```
     <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="SearchDistributor"
                   @bind-Value="createAccountModel.Region"
                   EnableDropDown="true"
                   ShowDropDownOnFocus="true"
                   MinimumLength="0"
                   placeholder="Search by distributor name" class="form-control">
    <SelectedTemplate Context="RegionVm">
        @RegionVm.Name
    </SelectedTemplate>
    <ResultTemplate Context="RegionVm">
        @RegionVm.Name
    </ResultTemplate>                                   
</BlazoredTypeahead>

private async Task<IEnumerable<RegionVm>> SearchDistributor(string searchText)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(regions.Where(x => 
  x.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(searchText.Trim().ToLower())).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the Blazored.Typeahead component?

Comment: Yes..Blazored.Typeahead component..

Answer (score 0):

Blazored Typeahead has a MinimumLength parameter with a default of 1.

If you want it to search for a zero length, try setting MinimumLength to 0

Comment: Tried using MinimumLength to 0 ..still does not work